# Vue Router with AWS Authenticator

Tags: javascript, vue.js, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Amplify and the Vue 3 Authenticator component to handle user login. Once logged in the user is routed to the correct path and when using the `auth.signOut()` method, correctly sets the URL back to the base, which is the same as the login page.

The login is handled in the `App.vue` component like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <Authenticator>
        <template v-slot:header>
          <div class="text-center">Login Page</div>
        </template>
      </Authenticator>
    </div>
    <template v-if="auth.route === 'authenticated'">
      <layoutComponent></layoutComponent>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>
```

The login page is the base url ([www.mySite.com](http://www.mySite.com)), and using the AWS Hub, it routes via this logic:

```
Hub.listen('auth', ({ payload: { event, data } }) => {
  if (event === 'signIn') {
    userStore.isUserSignedIn = true;
    router.push({ path: '/welcome' })
  } else if (event === 'signOut') {
    backendStore.isUserSignedIn = false;
      auth.signOut();
      router.replace({ path: '/' })
  }
});
```

The `/welcome` route has a log out button that works well, and navigates back to the [www.mySite.come](http://www.mySite.come). I am trying to have the user sign out on page refresh, but the `/welcome` route remains and gives a 403 error. I want it to return to the base URL.

The refresh logic is as follows:

```
async function getUser() {
  try {
    const session = await Auth.currentSession();
    userStore.userData = session;
  } catch (error) {
    userStore.userData = null;
  }
}


onUpdated(() => {
  getUser()
  if (!userStore.userData) {
    handleSignOut()
  } ;
})
```